# Recursive program to insert a star between pair of identical characters

Tags: c++, recursion

```
void pairStar(char input[]) {
    int len = strlen(input);

    if(input[0] == '\0'){
        return ;
    }
    if(input[0] == input[1]){

        for(int i = len; i >= 2; i--){
            
       input[i] = input[i-1];
        }
        
        input[2] = input[1];
        input[1] = '*';
    }
    pairStar(input+1);
    
}
```

what is the mistake in this code. I couldn't find out.
if I entered `aaaa`, `abaa` etc. it runs perfect.
but when i entered scatter is shows scat*ter?@
so what is the perfect solution ?

input string is aaaa  . so output is `a*a*a*a` instead of `a*aa*a`.

Comment: You appear to be overwriting the null terminator, and not adding it back at the end of the array. How about using `std::string` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You do not copy terminating character `\0`!
So when you have inserted a character termination of string is undefined.

Note also that proper answer for `aaaa` should be `a*a*a*a` (or `a*aa*a` depending on problem definition).

Split argument to define soruce and destination and use separate buffers.

```cpp
void copyAddStarToPairs(const char *src, char *dst)
{
    *dst = *src;
    if (!*dst) return;
    dst++;
    char prev = *src++;
    if (prev = *src) *dst++ = '*';
    copyAddStarToPairs(src, dst);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use `std::string` as your char buffer may not be long enough.

```cpp
#include <string>
using std::string;
void pairStar(string & s, int st) {
    if (st >= (int)s.size() - 1)
        return;
    else if (s[st] == s[st + 1]) {
        s += ' ';
        for (int i = (int)s.size() - 1; i > st + 1; i--)
            s[i] = s[i - 1];
        s[st + 1] = '*';
        st++;
    }
    pairStar(s, st + 1);
}

int main() {
    string s = "aadqwedabbbbb*dqwdasd";
    pairStar(s, 0);
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the line `input[len+1]='\0';` after the line`input[1]='*';`.

What happens actually is that once you append '*',you aren't appending the '\0' character. This line will append it to the end that means string end here for the first call that you made. So recursive function will also do the same, it will add '\0' character at the end letting know that string ends here.

Consider an example:
aa is a string of length 2 and and after adding star the length of string will become 3 so input[len+1] will be input[2+1]=input[3].
So character next to the moved character will be '\0' character everytime.

PS: this is my first time adding an answer on stackoverflow...

Comment: Could you please expand on why these changes should be made so that people reading your answer can better learn about what they're doing wrong?

Comment: Actually i am new to answering questions. I explained it as much as I can. Thanks.

Comment: That's alright. Your edits have really improved the answer. Just keep in mind that it's better to help people *learn* how to do something right, than it is to just fix their code for them.

Answer (score 0):

I offer to solve this problem, using the algorithm **Depth first search**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
const int maximumSize=40;
string symbols="aadqwedabbbbb*dqwdasd";
string symbolsNew;
vector<int> visited(maximumSize, 0);
template<class Type>
void showContent(Type input)
{
    for(int index=0; index<input.size(); ++index)
    {
        cout<<input[index];
    }
    return;
}
void depthFirstSearch(int current, int previous)
{
    if(visited[current]==1)
    {
        return;
    }
    visited[current]=1;
    symbolsNew.push_back(symbols[current]);
    int interactions=0;
    for(int next=(current+1); next<symbols.size(); ++next)
    {
        if(interactions!=0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(symbols[current]==symbols[next])
        {
            symbolsNew.push_back('*');
        }
        ++interactions;
    }
    for(int next=current; next<symbols.size(); ++next)
    {
        depthFirstSearch(next, current);
    }
    return;
}
void solve()
{
    depthFirstSearch(0, -1);
    cout<<"symbols <- ";
    showContent(symbols);
    cout<<endl<<"symbolsNew <- ";
    showContent(symbolsNew);
    return;
}
int main()
{
    solve();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
symbols <- aadqwedabbbbb*dqwdasd
symbolsNew <- a*adqwedab*b*b*b*b*dqwdasd
```

Answer (score 0):

void pairStar(char input[]) {
int len = strlen(input);

```
if(input[0] == '\0'){
    return ;
}
if(input[0] == input[1]){

    for(int i = len+1; i >= 2; i--){
        
   input[i] = input[i-1];
    }
    
    input[2] = input[1];
    input[1] = '*';
}
pairStar(input+1);
```

}

Comment: u have to add null in the end of the string as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
void helper(char input[], int start)
{
  if (input[start] == '\0')
  {
    return;
  }

  helper(input, start + 1);
  if (input[start] == input[start + 1])
  {
    for (int i = strlen(input); i >= start + 1; i--)
    {
      input[i + 1] = input[i];
    }
    input[start + 1] = '*';
  }
}

void pairStar(char input[])
{
  helper(input, 0);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.